# Display flashdata message in codeigniter callback function

Tags: php, codeigniter

I've this registration function and the related callback to check if an username already exists in the database. It works all perfectly, but I have problems with flashdata message

Here's the code:

```
/*
* Checks registration
*/
public function verify(){

$this->form_validation->set_rules('nome', 'Nome', 'trim|required|min_length[2]|xss_clean');
$this->form_validation->set_rules('cognome', 'Cognome', 'trim|required|min_length[2]|xss_clean');
$this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'Username', 'trim|required|min_length[4]|xss_clean|callback_check_username');
$this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'Email', 'trim|required|valid_email');
$this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'trim|required|min_length[4]|max_length[32]');
$this->form_validation->set_rules('password_conf', 'Password Confirmation', 'trim|required|matches[password]');

if($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
{
    $this->session->set_flashdata('error_reg', 'Something goes wrong, please check your registration form');    
    redirect('registration');   
}
else
{
    $this->registration_m->add_user();
    $this->session->set_flashdata('success_reg', 'Registration Successful!');
    redirect('registration');
}   
}


public function check_username($username){

$result = $this->registration_m->check_username_m($username);
if ($result) {
    $this->session->set_flashdata('username', 'Username già in uso, riprovare.');    
    return false;
} else {
    return true;
}
}
```

As you can see there's a redirect on the function `verify()`, and the flashdata before is correctly shown in case of errors.

**My Question is:** is there a way to show (in case of error) the flashdata inside the callback function without changing the logic of this piece of code?
Hope I was clear at all, cheers.

Comment: You want to show `flashdata('error_reg')` inside of `check_username`?

Comment: I want to show the error message on the `registration` page where I do the redirect in the function `verify`.

Comment: `echo $this->session->flashdata('error_reg')` ?

Comment: I don't think it's a good practice, especially using a framework, isn't? In addition, error message will be displayed in a particular div inside the view file

Comment: Ok but registration is another controller, routed, right? Then you could, on registration controller: `$data['error'] = $this->session->flashdata('error_reg');`, and `$this->load->view('page.php', $data);` on the view, simple `echo $error`;

Comment: I thought using a callback function there was something to handle error message on that function, anyway I'll try to use this solution for the moment.

Comment: No that I know of. If this became a pattern on your code, and your ensure that are using flashdata, you can write a library that reads a parameter and call it directly from view. Would be cleaner, since you're not involving controller to gather session values and reusable.

Comment: in your callback you should use $this->form_validation->set_message()
instead of $this->session->set_flashdata(). This way if there are any validation errors, the form_validation itself will create the flashdata message.

Comment: @DimitrisKontoulis, thanks a lot, I used the  `set_message() ` function with the same code above, but nothing changes, any ideas?

Comment: You generaly get no errors, or only for the already in use username?

Comment: Your trim rule may cause the problem, there. try to run the validaiton without it and tell us what happens, and if it was the reason , I will explain you what to do.

Comment: Finally I've solved loading a view instead ok making `redirect` to `registration` controller

Answer (score 0):

Modify your code as below

```
 public function check_username($username){    
   $result = $this->registration_m->check_username_m($username);
   if ($result) {
      $this->form_validation->set_message('check_username', 'The %s field can not be the empty');
      return false;
   } else {
      return true;
   }
  }
```

See differences in code

```
 $this->session->set_flashdata('username', 'Username già in uso, riprovare.');    

 $this->form_validation->set_message('check_username', 'The %s field can not be the empty');
```